# Can we use SELECT as an argument to REGEXP_LIKE?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, subquery, regexp-like

I have two tables - Table1 & Table2.

Table1 - Contains the regex pattern.

Table2 - Contains the file names.

Intention is to fetch rows from Table2 where file name matches a given regex pattern.

This works fine:

```
SELECT COLUMN2 FROM TABLE2 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (FILE_NAME, 'PATTERN', 'i');
```

However, the PATTERN needs to be fetched from Table1

So, I tried like:

```
SELECT COLUMN2 FROM TABLE2 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (FILE_NAME, SELECT PATTERN FROM TABLE1, 'i');
```

It seems either this construct is not supported or I am missing something obvious here.

Any advice/pointers will be a great help!

Comment: Try `REGEXP_LIKE (FILE_NAME, (SELECT PATTERN FROM TABLE1), 'i')` - but ensure that TABLE1 has exactly one row.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit That helped. I wonder how I missed trying this construct. Thanks for the quick and accurate response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the nested query in round brackets:

```
SELECT COLUMN2
FROM   TABLE2
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE ( FILE_NAME, ( SELECT PATTERN FROM TABLE1 ), 'i' );
```

This will only work if the nested query returns a single row you so may need to use:

```
SELECT COLUMN2
FROM   TABLE2
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE (
         FILE_NAME,
         ( SELECT PATTERN FROM TABLE1 WHERE unique_field = 'some value' ),
         'i'
       );
```

If the query will return multiple rows then you may need to use a join:

```
SELECT t1.PATTERN,
       t2.COLUMN2
FROM   TABLE1 t1
       INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2
       ON ( REGEXP_LIKE ( t2.FILE_NAME, t1.PATTERN, 'i' ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a join?

```
SQL> with
  2  table1 (pattern) as
  3    (select 'a' from dual union all
  4     select 'b' from dual
  5    ),
  6  table2 (file_name, column2) as
  7    (select 'Littlefoot', 'Not OK' from dual union all
  8     select 'Croatia'   , 'OK'     from dual
  9    )
 10  select b.file_name, b.column2
 11  from table2 b join table1 a on 1 = 1
 12  where regexp_like(b.file_name, a.pattern, 'i');

FILE_NAME  COLUMN
---------- ------
Croatia    OK

SQL>
```